# No core dump file generated on seg fault when a POSIX timer is armed

Tags: linux, posix

Whenever I use a POSIX timer (using `timer_create` and `timer_settime`) and a seg fault happens somewhere in my code, a core dump file is NOT generated. I tested this with a test fault (using a null pointer).

Commenting out `timer_settime` and running into the seg fault (null pointer usage) does result in having a core dump file (so ulimit is effectively set correctly), thus validating that everything else is Ok.

`timer_create` is called with sigevent set to `NULL`, so the default `SIGALRM` is used.

MORE INFO

I found that on certain systems (all are Ubuntu 12.04) the core file DO get generated. But not on others (particularly when running as a guess in a VM). On ALL platforms, not calling timer_settime and using an explicit segmentation fault (using a null pointer) cause a core dump file to be generated. I tested 2 bare metal and 2 VM (1 per bare metal). On one of the bare metal, running the VM and using the program in the bare metal did not generated the core dump but stopping the VM did permit the file to be generated. All physical have 8GB of RAM and the program Vm is few MB.